# how to insert new rows with values in the same sheet of an excel file in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to insert new rows while writing in Excel sheet.

Here is my code:

```
public static void addValuesInWorkbook(String pathAndFileName, String sheetName,
            int rowNum, String valuesString,String delimeter) {
        if(pathAndFileName.length() > 0 && sheetName.length() > 0 && rowNum >= 0 && valuesString.length() > 0 && delimeter.length() > 0)
        {
            String[] colValues= null;
            if("|".equals(delimeter))
                colValues = valuesString.split("\\|");
            else
                colValues = valuesString.split(delimeter);
            int cellnum = 0;
            FileInputStream fsIP;
            try {
                fsIP = new FileInputStream(new File(pathAndFileName));
             //Read the spreadsheet that needs to be updated
            if(rowNum > 0)
            {
                rowNum--;               //As row indexing starts from 0
            }
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fsIP); //Access the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);
            HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(((rowNum>0)?rowNum:0));
            HSSFCell cell=null;
            for(String colValue:colValues)
            {   if(row!=null){
                cell = row.getCell(cellnum);
                if(cell==null)
                    cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
                }
            else if (row == null)
                {
                    row =sheet.createRow(rowNum);                   //Create a row if it does not exist
                    cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
                }

                cell.setCellValue(colValue);
                cellnum++;
            }
            fsIP.close(); //Close the InputStream

            FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File(pathAndFileName));  //Open FileOutputStream to write updates

            wb.write(output_file); //write changes

            output_file.close();  //close the stream  
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

        }
```

Values are getting inserted with headers(column names
) but whenever new rows are inserted it replaces the older row values.

Please help.

Comment: Please explain what wrong in your code in terms of what you are expecting and what it is showing. Your question is not clear to me..

Answer (score 6):

This is because you are creating new rows on a row index which already has values.
You need to shift the existing rows 1 row down, so the index you want to insert a row is "free".

In other words, "createRow()" will always create a new row and index x, no matter if there is already one.

Use sheet.shiftRows(..)
See:
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#shiftRows(int, int, int)

The first argument should be the index of the row where you want to insert something, the second one the number of your last row and the third one should be 1. So all rows beginning from x will be shifted one row down and you can insert your row at x.

Example: every line is a row with content.

```
1 ----------------------
2 ----------------------
3 ---------------------- < you want to insert a new row at index 3
4 ----------------------
5 ----------------------
6 ----------------------
7 ----------------------
```

shiftRows(3,7,1) will do this:

```
1 ----------------------
2 ----------------------
3 empty row 
4 ---------------------- < your "old" row #3
5 ----------------------
6 ----------------------
7 ----------------------
8 ----------------------
```

createRow(3), set cell values:

```
1 ----------------------
2 ----------------------
3 ////////////////////// < your new row #3 witht he new content
4 ---------------------- < your "old" row #3
5 ----------------------
6 ----------------------
7 ----------------------
8 ----------------------
```

Comment: what will be the start row,end row and number of rows.because i guess if 1 is the numbers of rows(third one),it will insert only one row...Please help????

Comment: I am doing row = sheet.shiftRows(1, 10, 1); and i m getting error :cannot convert from void to HSSFRow.

Comment: shiftRows does not return a row. Just use shiftRows and then createRow(index)

Comment: sheet.shiftRows(1, 10, 1);
             sheet.createRow(rowNum); 
                 cell = row.createCell(cellnum);   I have done this..is this correct????

Comment: This should work for one row. But you need to put in the parameters for shift-rows dynamically. You solution will move the first to the tenth row one row down

Comment: okay..how can i add the values dynamically usig shiftRows() method..Please help

Comment: You should be able to do this with basic java knowledge