# XSSFSheet removeRow(row) method throws ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I am trying to read xlsx file. I am using poi 3.10-FINAL.

My code is

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("abc.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
row_count = 0;

for (int k = 0; k < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); k++) {
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(k);
    if (sheet.getLastRowNum() > 0) {
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next(); // throws ConcurrentModificationException
            if (row_count == 0) {
                col_count = row.getLastCellNum();
                //Do something
            } else {
                if (row.getCell(1).equals("XYZ")) {
                    sheet.removeRow(row);  //throws XmlValueDisconnectedException
                }
            }
            row_count++;
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute my code without `sheet.removeRow(row)`, it works fine. But when I add removeRow call it throws XmlValueDisconnectedException exception.

Can any one please help me why I am getting this exception.

**Update:**

I am quite surprised but now I am getting `ConcurrentModificationException` exception. Once it executes removeRow() and then when it returns to rowIterator.next() it throws the exception. I have mentioned location of exception in the code.
The stack trace is

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap$ValueIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.app.services.ExecuteImport.uploadFile(ExecuteImport.java:144)
    at com.test.app.controller.MyController.upload(MyController.java:271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the stack trace

Comment: Please find my updated question

Comment: Then you have your answer, you are attempting to delete while you are iterating through the collection. You can't do that.

Comment: Then how can i delete it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you try to remove a row using an iterator while iterating, you "confuse" the iterator.
Do it like this:

```
List<Row> toRemove = new ArrayList<Row>()
  while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next(); // throws ConcurrentModificationException
            if (row_count == 0) {
                col_count = row.getLastCellNum();
                //Do something
            } else {
                if (row.getCell(1).equals("XYZ")) {
                  toRemove.add(row);
                }
            }
            row_count++;
        }
// loop the list and call sheet.removeRow() on every entry
    ...
```

See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Comment: Thanks, using your code it is not throwing any exception. But I have one problem, after iterating toRemove list and calling removeRow method, my excel is not getting updated. Do I need to write it back to same location?

Comment: Yes, but make sure it is not opened and used by another programm.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am accepting your answer. I have just one question, `removeRow` method is removing the content of row but it is not deleting the row. So I am getting blank row in the excel.

Comment: You need to shift the remaning rows. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927438/how-to-insert-new-rows-with-values-in-the-same-sheet-of-an-excel-file-in-java/24927546#24927546. But you need to shift them up in your case

Comment: I have the same issue, I tried using iterator.remove method inside loop so concurrentmodification exception is not thrown.but the functionility to remove the current row not working